# Best way to split data of varying length into columns

Tags: regex, vim, notepad++

I have some data that includes 4 columns. First column is a place and last three columns are numbers or ranges of numbers.

What is the best way to split this data into four columns?

```
Red Coast Van 240-250 240-250 285-365
Beanbelt 310-400 310-400 450-540
North Star 310-400 310-400 450-540
Hamilton Fines, TA 380-390 380-390 505-530
Western Beanbelt 310-400 310-400 450-525
Main, PA 370-380 370-380 505-525
Dust Dodge, NY 380-390 380-390 520-525
Midwest Bean Belt (Des) m 400-475 400-475 572-615
```

Desired Output

```
Red Coast Van; 240-250; 240-250; 285-365
Beanbelt; 310-400; 310-400; 450-540
North Star; 310-400; 310-400; 450-540
Hamilton Fines, TA; 380-390; 380-390; 505-530
Western Beanbelt; 310-400; 310-400; 450-525
Main, PA; 370-380; 370-380; 505-525
Dust Dodge, NY; 380-390; 380-390; 520-525
Midwest Bean Belt (Des) m; 400-475; 400-475; 572-615
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 3):

It's completely simple to do this in `Vim`:

```
:%s/ \(\d\)/; \1/g
```

You instantly get the result you want. ( 24 substitutions on 8 lines )

Answer (score 2):

Notepad++

1. Ctrl+H
2. Find: (.+) (\d+-\d+) (\d+-\d+) (\d+-\d+)$
3. Replace: \1; \2; \3; \4;
4. Check the Regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example and description, it looks like columns 2nd, 3rd, and 4th are space-separated. Therefore you can do this using `awk` the following way:

- set the input field separator `FS` to space and the output field separator `OFS` to `;` (you can do this *una tantum* in the `BEGIN` procedure);
- join all the fields from `$1` to `$(NF - 3)` (i.e. the columns from the 1st to the 4th to last one) in a single field, `$1`;
- shift the remaining fields `$(NF - 2)`-`$NF` to `$2`-`$4` and adjust `NF` to `4`;
- print the modified record.

From words to code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS = " "; OFS = "; " }
{
  for (i = 2; i <= NF - 3; ++i)
    $1 = $1" "$i
}
{
  $2 = $(NF - 2)
  $3 = $(NF - 1)
  $4 = $NF
  NF = 4
}
{ print $0 }' youfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged `vim`, here's a Vim solution:

```
:%s/ \(\d\+-\d\+\) \(\d\+-\d\+\) \(\d\+-\d\+\)$/; \1; \2; \3/
```

which can be "prettified" with `verymagic`, or `\v`:

```
:%s/\v (\d+-\d+) (\d+-\d+) (\d+-\d+)$/; \1; \2; \3/
```

Note that there's no need to match whatever the first column is made up of; you only need to match the last 3 columns and prepend `;` to each.

The above solution **does not** make any assumption on how the first column is structured. If, instead, the first column is guaranteed not to contain a digit preceded by space, than an easier solution is possible (which is the slim version of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60234053/5825294)):

```
:%s/\ze \d/;/g
```

Obviously, if any of your lines is of the form

```
Western 666 Beanbelt 310-400 310-400 450-525
```

this last solution will break the first column in two.

Comment: Is all that really necessary? `:%s/ \(\d\)/; \1/g` seems to work fine.

Comment: This would generate wrong results if the first "column" (which is described as a "place") contains a digit preceded by space.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you be more specific?

Comment: Put `Western 6 Beanbelt` instead of `Western Beanbelt` and see. FWIW, if you really want to go short, no need to capture anything, use `\ze`.

Comment: That's not in the OP's example, so it's irrelevant

Comment: OP has given a rather precise description of the last three columns (_are numbers or ranges of numbers_), whereas he's given a very vague descripton of the first column (_is a place_), therefore I do not want to rely on the assumption that the first column does not contain any digit preceded by space, just because 8 scant samle lines do not contain one. That's it.

Comment: FWIW, your example splits on the same thing, and the example shown doesn't include the corner case you mention.

Comment: No, I have intentionally considered the corner case which is not excluded at all by the description. Besides, what do you mean by _example splits on the same thing_?

Comment: Check again. Try it with `Dust 666 Dodge, NY 380-390 380-390 520-525`; the last short version you included splits on `666`. If you are concerned about corner cases which the OP is not including then you'll be here for infinity trying to work out `what if...`

Comment: Yes, it's written in my post that it is the slim version of your answer. I'll make it clearer in a moment. Infinity? No, at some point I give up.

Comment: If it doesn't work according to you then I wouldn't suggest it as part of your answer... just saying. And what if the address is `Western 666 Beanbelt, Suite 1-100`, then your solution probably will be in the same boat.

Comment: It **would** not work in a test case **slightly** more general than the OP's **sample** input file. But it does work in the specific case. Therefore I've described the "boundary" where the more robust solution can be substituted by the shorter, less robust solution. However I think downvoting my answer is a good next step for you to take.

Comment: I'm not trying to argue with you, so please don't take my comments the wrong way; I understand what you're saying, although unless it's obvious attempting to cover every corner case is nearly impossible. Cheers!

Comment: @l'L'l, yes, the same way I've considered this corner case, I could have considered that a range might be expressed by other than `\d\+-\d\+`; or even that a number can be fractional. I consider making these two distinctions (which are just examples) less important. It's just a matter of personal taste, which I would have set aside, if only the OP had written a question with enough info.

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` solution is also possible, which looks pretty much like the `vim` one, except that it has no fancy stuff (e.g. no `\d` in place of `[0-9]`):

```
sed 's/ \([0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\) \([0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\) \([0-9]\+-[0-9]\+\)$/; \1; \2; \3/' yourfile
```

Analogously, however, you can simplify it by means of the `-E` option

```
sed -E 's/ ([0-9]+-[0-9]+) ([0-9]+-[0-9]+) ([0-9]+-[0-9]+)$/; \1; \2; \3/' yourfile
```